# JSP Error messages don't show when using Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

This is my repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepo extends CrudRepository<Product,Integer> {

public List<Product> findAll();
public Product findById(int id);
```

}

My Entity Bean:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "product_id")
private Integer id;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "product_name")
private String productName;
```

Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/add-product")
String addProduct(@Validated @ModelAttribute("product")Product product, BindingResult bindingResult){


    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        System.out.println("has errors: " + bindingResult.toString());
    }

    System.out.println( "adding Product ..." );

    productService.save(product);

    return "redirect:/products/success";
```

This is my view

```
<form:form action="add-product" method="post" modelAttribute="product">
    <label for="productName">Product Name</label>
    <form:input path="productName" id="productName" type="text" placeholder="Add product name"/>
    <form:errors path="productName" />
...
```

It just works fine when using Hibernate SessionFactory to store to database, like this:

```
// A shorter way to save customer
    Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    currentSession.saveOrUpdate(customer);
```

but when replacing it with Spring Data JPA, it starts throwing exceptions and return 500 html pages instead of just rendering the error field as it used to be.

There are 4 exceptions thrown:

```
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.luv2code.springdemo.entity.Product] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='must not be empty', propertyPath=productName, rootBeanClass=class com.luv2code.springdemo.entity.Product, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty.message}'}
]


javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convertCommitException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:77)
    org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:71)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:536)



org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
```

Previously, without using JPA, the validation error message shows in the view `<form:errors />`, not thrown as an exception with 500 http error code. What do I miss here?

Comment: Care for sharing the exceptions. Also you don't need the `findAll` and `findById` those are already provided for you. No need to add them again.

Comment: @M.Deinum. Please Check the question update with the exception.

Comment: You aren't checking if there are validation errors and proceed to save the entity. When both JPA and validation API are used JPA will also use this for validation. This fails and results in an exception. When using plain hibernate this isn't the case and you basically store an invalid object in the database. So it isn't really JPAs fault but the way you have implemented your controller.

Comment: Still, I don't understand what need to be done … please add an answer instead of a comment, and clarify exactly what need to be changed to avoid the exception. Thanks!

Comment: I would appreciate also if you clarify how will that affect the views instead of throwing them as an error?

Comment: `When using plain hibernate this isn't the case and you basically store an invalid object in the database` --> No, Error messages returned to the view and nothing stored in the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you see has nothing to do with Spring Data JPA but the fact that you switched from plain hibernate (judging from your code snippets) to JPA.

When using JPA and using JSR-303 those will work together to prevent invalid entities from being entered in the database by throwing the validation exception. When using plain Hibernate this doesn't happen (at least the exceptions don't propagate).

Which was due to you have written your request handling method. In case of errors in the model you just do a `System.out` and happily continue the method, what you should have been doing there is return to the original view instead (I assume `products/add-product`).

```
@PostMapping("/add-product")
String addProduct(@Validated @ModelAttribute("product")Product product, BindingResult bindingResult){


    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        System.out.println("has errors: " + bindingResult.toString());
        return "products/add-product";
    }

    System.out.println( "adding Product ..." );

    productService.save(product);

    return "redirect:/products/success";

}
```

Basically you failed at handling the case of errors properly leading to exceptions being thrown due to the JPA and javax.validation working in a united fashion.

Comment: Can you please let me know how to show the error on the view page using JPA, since `<form:errors />` is not working. Thanks!

Comment: It has nothing to do with JPA. Also without having your actual code it is impossible to tell. One thing is that if you use a redirect you loose your model and thus your errors.

Comment: What you said about exception propagation is very true, the problem has been avoided by just adding exception handling to the product saving part. On the other hand, what you said about the returned view is also true, it should be the one that has the error. I'm going to accept your answer … I would just recommend that you remove the code snippet in your answer, as it's a bit misleading to the source of the problem, which is the error propagation as I mentioned earlier in the comment. Stay Cool!

Comment: It isn't the propagation it is the fact you don't properly handle the fact that there are validation errors in your controller. You shouldn't be calling save if there are validation errors.